# How to sent File (Image) along with String parameters in the Body of a POST api (Volley)

Tags: android, android-volley

Was sending the collection of String Params in the Hashmap in the Api. Now it is required to add a parameter File that has to be an Image.

The body of the POST api looks as below:

```
Key1, Value1, Text
Key2, Value2, Text
Key3, Value3, File
```

I have seen many examples of Multipart requests but none solved the issue. 
Looking for an approach/example.

Comment: What does the server expect? Do you control the server as well?

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: It's alternative way to sending Image as a File.**

You can try converting Image to BASE64 String, and send it as a string.

First, convert your bitmap to byte array:

```
//can use lower value than 100 for more compression or change compression format as JPEG

ByteArrayOutputStream bAOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bAOS);
byte[] byteArray = bAOS.toByteArray();
```

Then, encode it to BASE64 String:

```
String encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Finally put it to your hashmap as a String.